# Got error "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Joke.id" in Prisma2

Tags: javascript, prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I have a simple `prisma.schema` ⸺

```
model Joke {
  id      String @default(cuid()) @id
  author  Author
  content String @unique
}

model Author {
  id    String @default(cuid()) @id
  name  String
  jokes Joke[]
}
```

And this is my `Query` ⸺

```
t.list.field('getJokeByAuthor', {
    type: 'Joke',
    args: {
        name: stringArg(),
    },
    resolve: (_, {name}, ctx) => {
        return ctx.photon.authors.findMany({
            where: {
                name,
            },
            select: {
                jokes: true,
            },
        });
        // return ctx.photon.jokes.findMany({
        //   where: {
        //     author: {
        //       name,
        //     },
        //   },
        // });
    },
});
```

The commented one works while the uncommented doesn't & gives me error `"Cannot return null for non-nullable field Joke.id."`. Why? I want to access jokes by a particular author by calling `ctx.photon.authors`. How can I achieve that?

Also, `getJokeByAuthor`'s return type is `[Joke]`? Where does it get that? Shouldn't it be `[Author]` now that I'm returning `ctx.photon.authors`?

Comment: You're specifying the type for the field right there in your code: `type: 'Joke'`

Comment: Do all the jokes in your database actually have an `id` value?

Comment: @DanielRearden yes. `Joke` table has 3 fields: `author`, `content` & `id`. `Author` table has 2 fields: `id` & `name`. `Author` field's `id` is equal to `Joke` field's `author`. Idk how I'm supposed to solve this?